# How to make SublimeText support Python 3's annotations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

I tested both SublimeText 2 and 3 and both are buggy:

If you test this code, you'll notice all code right after the `:` will not be syntax highlighted properly.

```
def foo(a, b) -> str:
    # Nothing gets properly colored from here
    # A bunch of code…
    return "bar"
```

I found some links explaining how to add your own syntax highlighting rules but I didn't find how to modify those already implemented in a attempt to fix them.

**EDIT:** Now knowing where to modify default syntax highlighting rules thanks to MattDMo, I tried to change line 385 of my file

```
        <key>end</key>
        <string>(\))\s*(?:(\:)|(.*$\n?))</string>
```

to

```
        <key>end</key>
        <string>(\))\s*(?:\->\s*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\s*)?(?:(\:)|(.*$\n?))</string>
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: I'm currently working on improving the built-in Python syntax, if anyone wants to contribute to [the project](https://github.com/MattDMo/PythonImproved) please feel free.

Comment: @MattDMo Does your `Python.tmLanguage` already fix the problem I'm having? If so, you could consider posting this as an answer as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't yet, which is why I didn't post an answer. I actually just found out about annotations recently myself - sorry, I haven't read each and every PEP :) - so I'll see if I can figure something out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created my own version ~2 months ago, it still has some *(serious)* bugs, so don't hesitate to report those bugs on this github page or contribute a fix for it:

https://github.com/petervaro/python

*Although there is a Cython version which is generated from the same file as the Python itself -> but it's absolutely a work-in-progress tmLanguage, so don't use it!:)*

---

***UPDATE:*** It is now "stable" and ready for the serious work, so use it, share it, and please report bugs! :)